# How to Handel Multiple Events /Listeners in GeoChart of GooleCharts

Tags: google-visualization

Good Morning,
 I am trying to handle two events on a single GeoChart,but i am not getting result ,
Only One Event was handling at a time .
The following code is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

function drawMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);

    var options = {};
    options['dataMode'] = 'regions';

    var container = document.getElementById('regions_div');
    var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(geomap, 'select', sampleselectevent);
    function sampleselectevent() {alert('I am an sampel event'); }

    geomap.draw(data, options);

     google.visualization.events.addListener(geomap, 'drawingDone', showcmpltd);
     function showcmpltd() {alert('Data collection is completed to dispaly chart'); }


};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which one is not working? For some reason its not drawing in my browser